# How to prompt the user to be required to input Validation for Minimum and Maximum Price?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I was thinking what we can do is that when they search using just the minimum price (Price From) and click search it would show the message please fill out maximum budget. Here's the website http://www.phpropertydeals.com and click the search min. and max, can we make when i add price in(Price from) then the (Price to) will prompt a required field. but if there's no input , in this part will continue to search.

```
<div class="mini-field">
                                <input input name="pricefrom" class="txt-field-input-mini formattingNumber" placeholder="Price from" style="width:159px;">
                                <input input name="priceto" class="txt-field-input-mini formattingNumber" placeholder="Price to" title="Please input maximum price budget" style="width:159px;">
                            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pricefrom = $('input[name="pricefrom"]'); 
  $(pricefrom).on('click', function() {
    if($('input[name="priceto"]').val().length < 1) {
      alert("You must insert Maximum price!");
    }


  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('input[name="priceto"]').val().length < 1) {
        alert("You must insert Maximum price!");
    } else {
        $( "#myform" ).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes this is correct to, but when the user add price from it should have a automatic field required in Price to saying "Please input maximum price budget"

Comment: when i add price from the price to it will required to the user that he/she add the max price.

Answer (score 0):

assign id to input tag like below code

```
<input input name="priceto" class="txt-field-input-mini formattingNumber" placeholder="Price to" title="Please input maximum price budget" style="width:159px;" id="min">
                            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#min').on('click', function() {
    if($('input[name="priceto"]').val().length < 1) {
      alert("You must insert Maximum price!");
    }


  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: wait ill try this answer

Comment: Hello @manuyd yes this is correct to, but when the user add price from it should have a automatic field required in Price to saying "Please input maximum price budget"

Comment: you mean "price to" input field will not be shown by default and you want to add when "price from" input field is not empty, is it what you want?

Comment: before i input required then there's a text "Please input maximum price budget" but when i click search that field only required. i want to create when i input in "Price From" then the field of "Price to" Will have a required prompt that user should input something in that field.

Comment: I think that is currently working except it worked on when click on "price to" field but if you want to validate on click of search button then replace $('#min') with $('search') and condition like if($('max').val().length > 0 && $('min').val().length < 1){ alert('Enter something on price to field message');}

Comment: or lets try this "you mean "price to" input field will not be shown by default and you want to add when "price from" input field is not empty, is it what you want? "

Comment: the default the max price will hide first then when i add min. price then the maxprice will be shown.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say can you refer me any site similar to your requiremennt

Comment: hello , what im trying to say is. when i add min price then automatic the max price will be require field.